# Pitch detection with computeSpectrum() return FFT values

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, signal-processing, fft

- I'm developing using Actionscript 3.0 for Flash Player 10.3
- I'm using **computeSpectrum()** on a loaded .mp3
- Running *Event.ENTER_FRAME* to get snapshots of each sample in an byteArray
- The ByteArray contains 512 values (256 for each channel). These values are FFT Spectrum, ranging from 0 to 1.
- I can't use the peak frequency for each of the samples (as I found found out!) because the highest value is not necessarily the fundamental frequency!
  As a result I'm getting lots of random values all over the place!
  Of course I'm getting some correct too, but that's not enough!

I found out about **auto-correlation**...
Can someone give me an example on how I could use it?

Or links, or example scripts even from other scripting languages to get a grip on it?

Regards
initcode

Comment: Do you want to do autocorrelation on the original waveform, or on the FFT?

Comment: I think I'll prefer on FFT, simply 'cos I'm trying to detect the pitch on something which a user just recorded and is not saved anywhere...exists as ByteArray in Flash Player

Comment: I mean, you can do 1. FFT(signal), 2. Autocorr(signal), or 3. Autocorr(FFT(signal)).  Also 4. FFT(FFT(signal)) ("cepstrum")  I believe all have been used for pitch detection, though I don't know which are best for voice.

Comment: Hi, so how did it go? Did you manage to get it work? Im working on a very similar project. Also using this http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/...
Please share your findings in the world of sound :). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you already understand how to get an FFT spectrum, right?

[image: spectrum] http://flic.kr/p/7notw6

But if you're looking for the fundamental (green dot), you can't just use the highest peak.  It's not necessarily the fundamental.  In my example, the actual fundamental is 100 Hz, but the highest peak is 300 Hz.

There are a lot of different ways you could find the true fundamental, and each works better in different contexts.  One thread on comp.dsp mentions "FFT, cepstrum, auto/cross-correlation, AMDF/ASDF".

For a simple example, each of the red dots is 100 Hz away from its neighbor, so if you used a peak-finding algorithm and then averaged together the distance between each harmonic and the next, you'd find the fundamental, but this would fail if any of the peaks were missed, or extra peaks included, or if the signal was symmetrical and only contained odd harmonics (1f, 3f, 5f).  You'd need to find the mode and then throw away outliers and then average.  This is probably an error-prone method.

You could also do an autocorrelation of the original waveform.  Conceptually, this means sliding a copy of the waveform past itself, and finding the delay at which it best lines up with itself (which will be one complete cycle).  In normal implementation, [we use the FFT, though, to speed it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Efficient_computation).  Autocorrelation is basically

- IFFT(FFT(signal)⋅FFT(signal)*)

where * means complex conjugate, or time reversal.  [In Python, for instance](https://gist.github.com/255291):

```
correlation = fftconvolve(sig, sig[::-1], mode='full')
```

and the source for fftconvolve() is relatively simple: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L133

Comment: That picture is worth 1.0E03 words.

Comment: @rajah9 Assuming an average of 6 characters per word, this 48 kB image is only 12.5% efficient at conveying information, then.  :)

Comment: If I had to choose a free C++ library to apply pitch detection which one would you suggest, please? I'm currently looking into Adobe Alchemy which will allow me (in theory) communication between C++ libraries and Flash!

Comment: @initcode I don't know.  I'm only familiar with high-level stuff in Matlab and Python.

Comment: Hi endolith, I Still trying to solve the problem with the detection...Thank you for your answer... My problem is that everybody gives me good theory but no one explains in a more detail so I can start trying to figure out how to code the formula... I'll need to ask a but more details in the formula you gave me above and if you find the time you could explain it to me, please.

Comment: I have an FFT array, each sample gives me 512 values, 256 for each channel.
In your formula the 'signal' is each one these 'samples', correct?

so the FFT(signal) will be replace with the array of these 512 values?

What is the formula for FFT(signal)* ?
How do I write this down?
I'm not using any C library, remember I have to write the all thing in Actionscript...
So I have to figure it out...

And any formula for IFFT ?

The result for this formula will be what?
A frequency which it will represent the fundamental frequency?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @initcode: What do you mean by "channels"?  More than one signal?  Just work with one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Harmonic Product Spectrum method to estimate the distance (frequency difference) between overtone peaks in a frequency spectrum (FFT results), even if some peaks are missing, as long as there are not too many spurious frequency peaks (noise).

To do a Harmonic Product Spectrum, print the FFT out on semi-transparent paper and roll it up into a cylinder (or do the equivalent in software).  Wrap the cylinder tighter and tighter until the greatest amount of peaks overlap.  The circumference will be a good estimate of the pitch.  This works for any musical sounds that have lots of harmonics, even if a fundamental pitch frequency peak is missing or weak.

Answer (score 0):

[`Sound.extract()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29) result can be passed to [`SampleDataEvent.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html#data)

Comment: Thanks www0z0k,  
I'm already using SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA to the ByteArray!    
What I'm looking is a method to simulate auto-correlation on my FFT values to detect pitch!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

I haven't used `computeSpectrum()` before, but the first half of my career as a DSP engineer.

If it does what the docs say, then you don't need to autocorrelate the results.

In your byte array, the index represents the frequency bin, and the index value represents the magnitude of that particular frequency.

If by pitch detection, you mean find the strongest frequency, then you need to loop through the byte array and calculate the `sqrt(left*left+right*right)` for each index.  Find the max value of these.  The index of the max value represents thr strongest frequency.

Assuming fs=44.1kHz, and i is your index, then the strongest frequency is

f = (i/255) * (44100 / 2);

Keep in mind that you are limited by the bin spacing for frequency resolution.  If you need higher resolution, you need to interpolate the data.

Comment: Hi MPD,

Thank you for the reply...
I'm actually trying to detect the pitch as in note, not just the peak frequency in a sample bin.
the problem is that the fundamental frequency is not necessarily the highest frequency, so I have to find a way to autocorrelate to detect that frequency; Then is easy; I have already functions to return the correct note based on the frequency!

Comment: OK, then you need to read up some more on pitch detection algorithms.  There are a few ways to go about it.  There are some related questions here, but I haven't read them to see how much merit they have.  Autocorrelation is a time domain thing, though you can compute it using an FFT.  The problem is that computeSpectrum() doesn't give you the full FFT values back.  You are likely going to need to compute FFT using the raw data, or compute the autocorrelations in the time domain usine the raw data.