# Client-side Microphone Analysis of Notes

Tags: java, flash, audio, javafx

So I'm hoping to build an RIA that allows for the analysis of audio streaming from a user's microphone at any given point in time so I can detect what note this is. I think I can do the note detection with the frequency fairly easily but this kind of on-the-fly processing seems impossible in flash (my preferred choice) and I haven't found much on it I can understand in the form of a java applet (less preferred but ok).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there any way to do it in flash without huge lag by sending it to my server and back? If not, how can I do it in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SoundMixer to compute the spectrum. To detect the actual pitch you need further processing of the spectrum.

```
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(ba,true,0);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm

With the frequency spectrum you can do that in ActionScript on the client side. Computation is easy so it won't bother the user.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got it now. I've also found this: http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/an-even-faster-as3-fft/ , an FFT implementation that should help to point me in the right direction for 'processing of the spectrum'

Comment: OK. I'm kind of stuck. How can I process it further?

Comment: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~pdelac/154/m154paper.htm within the fequency Domain you can build the harmonic product spectrum to identify the Fundamental frequency.  That would be your pitch. Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283104/pitch-detection-with-computespectrum-return-fft-values

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at my spectrum analyzer code as well. https://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/
It uses the FFT class and real-time microphone input. To make a really simple pitch detector, you can just find the highest peak in the magnitude spectrum, and do a quadratic interpolation of the peak and the bins on either side to get sub-bin frequency resolution. Using the highest peak works fine if you're trying to identify single notes, and the instruments overtone structure is such that the fundamental is the strongest harmonic (which is often the case).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you very much. It seems weird to have you reply, almost like a celebrity :P. The amount of times I read that post is crazy :P. Unfortunately, I'm no DSP expert and feel well over my head so I've sidelined the project and hope to come back to it in the future when I have some more audio knowledge/

Comment: Hi Gerry, could you explain more on how to do a quadratic interpolation of the peak and bins?

Comment: Good explanation on quadratic interpolation here: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/parshl/Peak_Detection_Steps_3.html. Might look a little scary at first, but it's actually pretty simple. The basic idea is that you find the magnitude of a peak in the spectrum, and the magnitudes of the bins on either side of that peak. Using their relative magnitudes, you figure out how much to the right or left the real peak is.