# How to calculate the average frequency of an audio recording captured as a ByteArray in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, arrays, frequency, pitch

Keeping it simple for now but assuming i have a ByteArray full of sample data is it possible to calculate the average frequency (thus a pitch) from the entire recording?

Is this along the right lines? p = 69 + 12 x log2(f/440hz) ...

Excuse my ignorance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283104/pitch-detection-with-computespectrum-return-fft-values

Answer (score 4):

Your formula `p = 69 + 12 * log2(f / 440)` is for converting a frequency in Hz to a musical note (the [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) note number). For this though you need `f`, the frequency of the note in Hz, which is a little trickier to determine. For a pure tone (sinusoid) with no noise it's relatively straightforward, otherwise you'll need to look at using an [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) or other method to identify the frequency of interest.